# getting a gui program to start on boot

Tags: linux, terminal, raspberry-pi

I have a C program I wrote for debian on the raspberry pi that asks the user to enter a number, 1-4 which it then stores in a configuration file. This only happens if the configuration file is missing. I'd like to run this program on boot. Problem is, I can get it to run on boot, but haven't had any luck getting the terminal window to show up so I can see it. I've tried editing /etc/rc.local and adding commands there. I've tried editing crontab. I've tried all the tricks with "export display=:0 && command". Any suggestions?

#### Edit:

Here is the command I am actually running in /etc/rc.local:

```
x-terminal-emulator --command=/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/initialConfig/./initialConfig.bin --display=:0
```

The program uses scanf() to capture keyboard input and display feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. In your users home directory you have to create a file called autostart at the path /.config/lxsession/LXDE/ and just add whatever command you want to execute after login to the autostart file.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to run any X window terminals during boot. The run level you're in doesn't have a X server running. So you could do something like this in your `/etc/rc.local` which could then collect input from the user and then call your executable with it.

```
#!/bin/sh
INPUT_STRING=hello
while [ "$INPUT_STRING" != "bye" ]
do
  echo "Please type something in (bye to quit)"
  read INPUT_STRING
  echo "You typed: $INPUT_STRING"
done

myexec $INPUT_STRING
```

This is only an example, you'd need to change it to suite your needs.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but still don't have anything showing up on the screen on boot. I originally had #!/bin/sh -i, but tried it both with and without -i. No luck. Could there be something wrong with my setup?